# Is it possible to remove/hide buttons from title bar?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I want to remove (or make transparent?) title bar buttons (minimize, close, maximize) from windows since I do not need them. Is it possible somehow to do that? I have disabled System Integrity Protection, so I'm okay even with "hacky" solutions if there are any...

Comment: a) I very much doubt it. The Mac interface hasn't been 'hackable' for at least a decade. b) why??

Comment: @Tetsujin: 1) Yabai window manager proves that it is possible to extend macos by controlling spaces, window borders, tiling and so on. So I think macOS is hackable in some way. 2) I use Yabai, so I do not need these buttons or title bars in general. And they look ugly :(